# How to implement breadcrumbs in spring MVC & Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, breadcrumbs

Hi friends I need your help to implement breadcrumbs in my project SpringMVC, JPA, thymeleaf. I found https://github.com/pawanspace/BreadCrumb-Spring-MVC example project as useful but I got stuck here.

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${sessionScope.currentBreadCrumb}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${entry.currentPage == true}">
            ${entry.label}
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
                <a href="${entry.url}">${entry.label}></a>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

The above code is written in JSP. Since I'm using thymeleaf, can any one help me to write this logic in thymeleaf or there is any other better way then this for implementing breadcrumbs in a SpringMVC project?

Comment: What is your question anyway? you have stuck on what? Whats wrong with the code you posted..Did you get any exception.? if any please post in your question.?

Comment: i am trying to implement the above codein thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this posting is abit old but basically what you are looking for is a way to iterate over a collection in Thymeleaf.  I recently did something very similar using bootstrap and Thymeleaf.

```
 <ul class="breadcrumb" >
     <li th:each="entry : ${sessionScope.currentBreadCrumb}">
         <a th:href="${entry.queryString}" th:unless="${entry.isCurrent}" th:text="${entry.label}">Home</a>
         <span th:if="${entry.isCurrent}" th:text="${entry.label}">Home</span>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Looking at this code snipet, you can control the appearance of the link (href) by using the thymeleaf attribute th:unless.  The span tag using, in a similar fashion the thymeleaf attribute th:if.

The "th:unless" is equivalent to doing a negative check using a "th:if".  It is really a matter of preference.

If you have questions about the conditional logic, check out the following link: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless

Looking at how this iterates over the collection, you will see the use of th:each="entry : ${sessionScope.currentBreadCrumb}", which resides inside the list item tag; entry becomes the iterator for the currentBreadCrumb collection.

Again if you have questions, about how to iterate check out this link: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach

Cheers!